# How to handle remote caching not responding with redis cache?

Tags: redis, quarkus

I'm currently implementing cache using redis. I'm using  only one instance of redis (deployed on ocp) as we don't have any redis cluster available.

My point is : I want my application still working properly event if redis is not available, but if it is not available I got an exception instead.
I had a look to the issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34779, and it seems a solution could be to use Smallrye fault tolerance, but with some boilerplate.

Is there another solution that I missed ?